# Put year label at start of year on axis

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2

I'm making a plot of water level data. I'm trying to alter the x axis labels so that the year label is placed on January 1st of each year, but it seems to place it close to the end. How do I do this?

##### Edit:

The problem in in the breaks=seq() section. The min date is Nov 2014. How do I set a start datetime of "2015-01-01 00:00:00"?

##### Current Code:

```
plotTitles <- list('Crose Mere'= 'Crose Mere',
                   'Sweat Mere new' = 'Sweat Mere',
                   'Whattall New' = 'Whattall'
                   )

scaleFUN <- function(x) sprintf("%.2f", x)

plotlist_controlSites <- list()

j = 1   # counter for plot title and index
for (datTime in DTW){
  plotName <- names(DTW)[j]
  j = j+1
  plot <- 
    datTime %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=DateTime)) +
    geom_point(aes(y=mAOD), col='grey') +
    geom_smooth(aes(y=mAOD), col='black', se=FALSE, span=0.1, method="loess") +
    theme_classic() +
    labs(y='Water Depth (mAOD)', x=NULL) +
    ggtitle(plotTitles[[plotName]][1]) + 
    scale_x_datetime(
      breaks=seq(min(datTime$DateTime), max(datTime$DateTime), 
                 by= "1 year"), date_labels="%Y",
                 limits = as.POSIXct(c('2015-01-01', '2022-01-01'))) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels=scaleFUN,  limits = c(50, 140)) +
    theme(text=element_text(size=20, family='Calibri Light')) +
    theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 1, 1), 'cm')) +
    theme(axis.title.y=element_text(margin=margin(t=0, r=20, b=0, l=0))) +
    theme(axis.title.x=element_text(margin=margin(t=20, r=0, b=0, l=0))) +
    theme(axis.title.y.right=element_text(margin=margin(t=0, r=0, b=0, l=20)))
  
  plotlist_controlSites[[plotName]] <- plot
}
```

##### Head of dataframe

```
structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1417107600, 1417111200, 
1417114800, 1417118400, 1417122000, 1417125600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), siteTemp = c(8.64, 8.65, 8.61, 8.53, 
8.45, 8.38), baroTemp = c(7.34, 6.4, 6.18, 6.21, 6.48, 6.8), 
    mAOD = c(NA, 72.5069999999999, 72.0069999999999, 71.7069999999999, 
    72.2070000000001, 72.3069999999998)), row.names = 22062:22067, class = "data.frame")
```

##### Current Output

This is a snippet of the plot. Basically the labels are like a year behind. So where it says 2022, that is the end of 2022 and should say 2023.

[image]

If I change the label to the form '%m-%Y', you can see where it is placing the label.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the range of `datTime$DateTime` it is difficult to say, but my guess is that `min(datTime$DateTime)` is **not** the 1st if January in this year, but closer to the end of the year.

Thus, you could use the following snippet:

```r
library(lubridate)
# ...
+ scale_x_datetime(
      breaks = seq(update(min(datTime$DateTime), month = 1L, day = 1L),
                   max(datTime$DateTime), 
                   by = "1 year"), 
      date_labels = "%Y",
      limits = as.POSIXct(c("2015-01-01", "2022-01-01")))
```

To confirm my theory, look at

```r
seq(min(datTime$DateTime), max(datTime$DateTime), by= "1 year")
```

and you will see that the breaks are at the **end**  and not at the **beginning** of the year.

Comment: I'm getting this error: Error: 'update' is not an exported object from 'namespace:lubridate'

Comment: Sorry my bad, just load `library(lubridate)` and remove `lubridate::`